# PreviewKeyDown-Event not always firing when ALT key is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Background: I am trying to display all available keyboard shortcuts when the user presses the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key - similar to the behavior in Office 2010.

But I am having trouble to detect when the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed because the `PreviewKeyDown`-Event is not always fired. More precisely: It is fired when the key is pressed for the first time, but when I release it and press it again, the event is not fired. That means, it is only fired every second time. I assume that this is related to the fact that the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is a special system key and triggers the window's main menu which somehow swallows the second event. Interestingly, the event does work for the *right* <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. Also, the `PreviewKeyUp`-Event is always fired for both keys (left and right).

I have also tried to handle the `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` messages directly, but the behavior is exactly the same.

I managed to get the desired behavior when I registered for the `InputManager.Current.PostNotifyInput` event, but this event is fired pretty often - even for every mouse movement etc. and I would like to avoid this overkill.

Any ideas how I can always be notified when the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed? How does Office 2010 do this? Maybe, is there an event which notifies if the window's menu is activated by pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key?

Comment: check this out `Key key = (e.Key == Key.System ? e.SystemKey : e.Key);`

Comment: search about AccessKeyManager, it's how [AccessText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.accesstext(v=vs.110).aspx) have implemented what you need

Comment: @dotctor: Thanks, I am aware of this. However, I cannot perform this check since the event is not fired at all! My handler is not called, so I cannot check the EventArgs.

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara: Thanks for the idea. I checked Microsoft's implementation and found out that the visibility of the line under the AccessKey is controlled by a Trigger using the `KeyboardNavigation.ShowKeyboardCuesProperty`. This property is set as a reaction to the `InputManager.PostProcessInput` which I already considered. So this seems to be the only solution. I did some performance tests and found out that it is not such a big deal... So I will probably use this solution, although I am not really happy with it.

Comment: @Close-voters: I do not think that this question is a request for debugging help. It is not a bug in my code, but it is a special handling of the `Alt` key on Windows systems. I think it is completely valid to ask for a solution to work around this special handling.

Comment: It may be an overkill for this task, but I used AutoHotkey for global key event handling before. You can integrate it to .net projects using [this](https://github.com/amazing-andrew/AutoHotkey.Interop)

Comment: @gehho: What did you do, to solve your problem?

Comment: @Rico-E It's been a while since I had that issue, but I assume that I have used `InputManager.PostProcessInput`, as written in my comment above. I can't provide any more details because I don't have access to that code anymore...